# broken proguard.txt in external AAR dependency (non-ascii characters)

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

It seems that Appsflyer 4.11.0 AAR has lots of non-ascii characters in its internal proguard.txt
As a result, gradle fails with this exception:

```
> Task :aaa-android:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForGeneralDebug
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before 'Л?' in line 20 of file '...\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\29b5b62e2aecc0fd037709d7255ea0ac\proguard.txt'
Thread(Tasks limiter_1): destruction

> Task :aaa-android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForGeneralDebug FAILED
Request to incrementing alive workforce from 0. Current workforce (dead or alive) 0
thread-pool size=4

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':aaa-android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForGeneralDebug'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':aaa-android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForGeneralDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
        ...

Caused by: java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before 'Л?' in line 20 of file '...\.gradle\caches\transforms
-2\files-2.1\29b5b62e2aecc0fd037709d7255ea0ac\proguard.txt'
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:268)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:65)
        ...
```

**The question is:**

1. Is it possible to ignore buggy proguard.txt from the external AAR?
2. Is it possible to set the locale to interprete the non-ascii characters with something meaningful?

Thanks in advance!
Andrei Isakov

I tried to clean gradle caches. I also tried to set the gradle locale like this:

```
GRADLE_OPTS="-Duser.language=us -Duser.country=US -DLANG=en_US.UTF-8 -DLANGUAGE=en_US:en -DLC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8"
```

or set the system variables in console. no effect :(

Answer (score 0):

Raising the version of gradle 5.1.1 -> 6.0.1 and android tools from 3.2.x to 3.5.2 solved the problem (both R8 and old Proguard now work wothout problems)